# coldfusion9 Htttp 404.2 error

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Hi i have windows vista and Coldfusion9 when i try to access the http://127.0.0.1/inetpub/wwwroot/ 
I am getting the following error

Server Error in Application "Default Web Site"

```
HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found

Description: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.

Error Code: 0x800704ec

Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler

Module: IsapiModule

Requested URL: http://localhost:80/

Physical Path: C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot

Logon User: Anonymous

Logon Method: Anonymous

Handler: AboMapperCustom-175270243
```

I restarted the CF Services/application server.
No use. Then  i checked in the IIS/Web sites/isapi and cgi restrictions which are empty.
When i click on IIS/(Right hand side )mylapTopName/Application Pools and Web sites/Default Websites.

Should i link Default websites to "C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot" ??

What should i do to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

I would be willing to bet that you have a web.config file that may have been copied from another server. If that is the case, remove that file. 
If that is not the case try running wsConfig.exe (do a search for it under the Coldfusion9 directory. To properly configure IIS for the coldfusion server for your site.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the "home" directory for your local IIS server would actually be pointing to inetpub/wwwroot, so that http://127.0.0.1/ would go straight there without needing to add /inetpub/wwwroot to the URL path.

Take a look here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ffd.html for information on web server management.  You probably specifically need to have a look at this : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf363a5d-7ffc.html on using the web server configuration GUI.